# Power via on game controller

Tags: pcb, usb, pinout

I've opened up a knockoff game cube controller and I want to know what the power via is labelled as. There is a 5v which is fine but **what are the 'v' and 's' pins?** Photo attached. The cable is a standard game cube plug but I'm wondering if its just USB and if I can therefore splice it into a USB plug.
Cheers[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not USB, seems V would be a 3.3V supply, and S the bidirectional data wire, The protocol is further described in the link below.

https://os.mbed.com/users/christopherjwang/code/gamecube_controller/wiki/Homepage